# Listbox display error :(

Tags: c#, listbox

Supposedly the listbox show the list of student's name and gender but instead its display Assignment2.Student. Pls help fix my problem :(

```
    private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;


        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        string line = "";


            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string name = "";
                string gender = "";

                char[] selected = line.ToCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < selected.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (selected[i] != '(')
                    {
                        name += selected[i];

                    }

                    else if (selected[i] == '(')
                    {
                        gender += selected[i + 1];
                        break;
                    }

                }

                Student student = new Student();

                student.setName(name);
                student.setGender(gender);

                studentListBox.Items.Clear();
                birthdatePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
                studentlist.addStudent(student);
                studentListBox.Items.Add(student);

        }

        sr.Close();


    }

    private void studentListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = studentListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        Student s = studentlist.findStudent(name);

        s.setName(studentNameTB.Text);
        s.setGender(genderTB.Text);
        s.setBirthDate(birthdatePicker.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Just override `ToString` method of `Student` class

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the ToString function for your Student class. The ListBox will then use this method to show the information you want about each one of your student :

```
public override String ToString()
{
    return name + " " + gender;
}
```

If you don't override it, the ToString method will just return the type of your object, here Assignment2.Student.

Comment: You forgot the opening curly brace and the `override` keyword

Comment: Another problem is that when i browse the .txt file, it only show one item(John (M) only) instead the list num of students inside the listbox.

Comment: Isn't that because you're doing "studentListBox.Items.Clear();", which remove all the items in your ListBox, before adding a new student ? Just do it once before your while, but not in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can optimize your code like follow

```
string[] students = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
foreach (string student in students)
{
    string[] split = student.Split('(');
    StudentList.Add(new Student() { Name = split[0], Gender = split[1][0].ToString() });
}
listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(StudentList.ToArray());
```

and for display problem I would advice to override `ToString()` function

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} / {1} ", Name, Gender);
}
```